# MySQL Group and Order by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sort the sum of each sales month by highest to lowest.

mysql

```
SELECT date_format(salesdate, "%M" "%Y") as "Month Year"
     , sum(salesamt) as "Sales" 
  from sales
 Group 
    By date_format(salesdate, "%M" "%Y")    
 Order 
    By "sales" DESC;
```

```
It will sort by month, but not by sales amount.

Thanks
```

Comment: You can include more than 1 term in the order by clause..

Comment: Including spaces in table/column identifiers is a recip for disaster

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
Order By "sales"
```

The "sales" is treated as a constant string, not a reference to a column. To make a reference to a column, use backticks when needed (sales does not need one as it contains no illegal characters, whereas "Month Year" has the space. To sort using both "Month Year" and "Sales" use

```
order by `Month Year`, Sales
```